# React JS and sublime text incompatibily

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, jsx

I use sublime text to learn React.js, and a I have a problem with syntax. When there is a / on my code, all the code after the / have a different color, as if the / change the syntax of the code.

for exemple, if a write :

```
export default class Featured extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h1> Featured </h1>
    );
  }
}
```

all the code have a correct color syntax until the , after the / in the  tag, all the syntax is orange .. I don't understand, I have install jsx / babel / react plugins on my sublime text ..

Does someone could help me ?

Thank !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need syntax highlighting especially built for JSX and ES6/Babel. Try this: https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime

Comment: you're welcome.  :)  if you could check the answer as "accepted" I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Working as expected

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, this syntax https://github.com/borela/naomi covers ReactJS, JSX, Flowtype and ES2017+ where I am adding support even for Stage 0 features.